# Form_Paint and AutoRedraw in VB6

Tags: vb6

Using VB6, I am aware that Form_Paint does not get invoked if AutoRedraw is true.

I have some code that only works consistently if invoked in Form_Paint.

This code (working in an MDI project) gets a handle to the currently active menu on the parent, via the GetMenu() API call. If not invoked in Form_Paint the call sometimes returns the old menu handle.

One of my forms has AutoRedraw = true. I have tried GetMenu(parent.hWnd) in Form_Activate, but this is too soon.

I've also tried overriding WindowProc and sending a WM_USER message from Form_Activate. This is an improvement, but still not consistent enough.

How do you call GetMenu(parent.hWnd) later in it's child form's lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the **GotFocus** event. It falls after the **Activated** event, and before the **Paint** event.